# Odd gsub error for a recode function in R when I didn't use the gsub function

Tags: r, syntax-error, gsub, recode

I regularly use the recode() function in R from the car library.  It works great.  However, now I'm getting an odd gsub error message and I've got no clue why since I haven't called the gsub() function in my commands.

I used the gsub() function the other day to pull commas out numeric values, but that was something completely different.  Since getting the error, I specified the car::recode() function and restarted R & reloaded only the car library, but still I get the same error.

The code below is just a simple recode exercise for my students and now I'm boggled. Any thoughts?

```
# enter grade data
> trust <- c("D","C","B","D","E","C","A","F","D","C")

# recode letters to numbers
> library(car)
> trust.r <- recode(trust(" 'A'=5; 'B'=4; 'C'=3; 'D'=2; 'E'=1; 'G'=0 "))
Error in gsub("\n|\t", " ", recodes) : argument "recodes" is missing, with no default

# Weird error.  Specify recode() from car library
> trust.r <- car::recode(trust(" 'A'=5; 'B'=4; 'C'=3; 'D'=2; 'E'=1; 'G'=0 "))
Error in gsub("\n|\t", " ", recodes) : argument "recodes" is missing, with no default

# Still weird error.  Flip " and ' symbols, just in case
> trust.r <- car::recode(trust(' "A"=5; "B"=4; "C"=3; "D"=2; "E"=1; "G"=0 '))
Error in gsub("\n|\t", " ", recodes) : argument "recodes" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: `recode` uses `gsub` internally. When you do `recode(trust(...))` you are using `trust` like it's a function, but above you define it as an object (because you have a parenthesis after it). I think the correct syntax is something like `recode(trust, recodes = "'A'=5; 'B'=4;...")`

Comment: Wow....now I'm embarrassed.  Total rookie mistake.  :)  Thanks!  Guess I was staring at my screen too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Gregor's comment is correct.  If you read the `?recode` page, you'll see

> **Usage**
>   recode(var, recodes, as.factor, as.numeric=TRUE, levels)

**Arguments**
**var** numeric vector, character vector, or factor.

> **recodes** character string of recode specifications: see below.

So, don't try to embed the `recodes` inside `var`

Comment: Thanks for the supporting comment Carl!  Total mistake on my end, but I probably started over-thinking the issue when I saw that error message and got confused.